# Detecting Firebase connection state uses huge amount of memory in react-native app

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

When I add the following code to my react-native app, memory usage soars from 40MB to 400MB in ten minutes (and keeps going) as soon as I take the app offline.

```
root.child(".info/connected").on("value", (snap) => {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    this.online = true;
    info("Going online");
    if (this.user) { /* counter already loaded */
       debug("posting offline transactions");
    }
  } else {
    this.online = false;
    info("Going offline");
  }
});
```

The app itself is entirely quiescent and the .on() listener is not getting triggered. When I bring the phone back online memory usage stabilizes but does not decrease.

I have no idea how to debug this. I cannot run the app under the Chrome debugger because the phone has to be online to connect to the debugger. I cannot use the iOS simulator because to bring that offline you have to bring the whole computer offline and then you get the error: `WebSocket connection failed`

The only way I have to debug is to view console.log messages in xcode and my app has lots of them, but nothing is happening in the app itself.

I need to monitor offline/online state in order to work around the fact that [Firebase transactions consume a large amount of memory](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/firebase-talk/OZTz5xqAQYE) when the app is used offline.

Comment: Having trouble believing this without a repro. Seems more likely that you're downloading a very large amount of data into memory when connected.

Comment: The problem is happening when **offline**. But if you want to know how much firebase network traffic is happening when online, the answer is very little. When the user taps a button, a few hundred bytes are exchanged.

Comment: Try turning on debug logging. That may help: `Firebase.enableLogging(true);`

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I must have been running with the JS bundle loaded over the net. When using a static bundle the problem is not there. Tho loading over the net is complete and the app appears to still work OK when going off line, somebody is apparently freaking out about not being able to reach the react packager server. The Firebase logs don't seem any different so not sure what's going on or why it only happens with .info/connected. Thanks for the help, Kato.